# create a user without logged out admin laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have 2 role user. Admin & user

i want to create a user using default form register in laravel when admin login. i've success to access register form without logged out admin, but when i click Register button. it redirect to dashboard and change to user dashboard.(admin logged out automatically). how to keep in admin mode when i create user?

Following example does not work:

```
protected function create(array $data) {
    $this->redirectTo = '/url-after-register';

   return User::create([...]);
}
```

Comment: Your applied middleware will cause the redirect. You probably applied the default middleware on the register page which will redirect every logged in user away.

Comment: I think what you actually want to describe is a user management page for admin users right? You should actually create a new route & page for this specfifc usecase since you do not want to register, but create new userse. Which is a huge difference. You do not want to be logged in as the freshly registered user etc.

Comment: But do you want to create these users hard coding them or with a GUI?

Comment: @FrankProvost i create crud for table users. but remember_token is null and password not hashed.

Comment: Well you can easily hash the password using bcrypt($password) and you do not need to set the remember_token - null is fine here